# Не хватает background при большом количестве содержимого страницы

Tags: jquery, css, css3

Мы имеем первые два тега : **html** и **body**.

Если указать background-image для тега body то браузер Opera не видит его.

Если указать background-image для тега html то другие браузера так же его не видят !

Что делать в этом случае ?

При записи вида :

```css
/* тут была синтаксическая ошибка неправильная скобка ( */
html,body{ 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    background-color:red;
    background-image:url(http://nevseoboi.com.ua/uploads/posts/2011-03/1300012981_oboitut.com_1050_nevseoboi.com.ua.jpg);
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

происходит дублирование фона что очень хорошо видно в мобильниках особенно при паралаксе ..

**Как поступать в этом случае ?**

**Вот к примеру сама суть вопроса** , страница имеет большую высоту и фон по просту не помещается по высоте , я хотел применить маленькое параксирование для фона но проблема сохранилась , что можно сделать в этом случае ?

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var movement = -parseInt($(this).scrollTop() / 50);
  $('body').css({
    backgroundPosition: 'center ' + movement + 'px'
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  background: #000000 url('http://nevseoboi.com.ua/uploads/posts/2011-03/1300012981_oboitut.com_1050_nevseoboi.com.ua.jpg');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

p {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos voluptatum, harum, ipsam blanditiis numquam expedita veritatis culpa esse nemo provident neque tempora quibusdam cupiditate quas soluta quod inventore error et. Atque, officia recusandae? Velit eveniet quos reprehenderit beatae illo voluptatum officia architecto sed nemo dicta aut reiciendis dolor, expedita odio dolore officiis quo ducimus delectus vitae laboriosam sequi molestiae. Quae et fugit eius delectus doloribus inventore, corrupti consequuntur, est suscipit quod temporibus animi fuga? Quos consequuntur autem consectetur. Facilis voluptate, architecto eaque asperiores numquam corrupti minus voluptatibus corporis dolores earum libero molestiae quisquam impedit! Eaque, suscipit perferendis. Esse adipisci, quisquam, enim sequi quas ipsam suscipit magnam, laudantium ipsum porro reiciendis placeat? Autem dolor assumenda sequi molestiae cupiditate culpa exercitationem tempore incidunt explicabo? Dolores alias quis cum, sequi eveniet consequatur nemo mollitia ab architecto atque, est nobis corrupti optio aliquam laborum consectetur! Porro doloremque, soluta iusto mollitia nemo, cum laboriosam unde consequatur asperiores sed architecto obcaecati. Cum, explicabo, in reiciendis molestias itaque at laudantium mollitia blanditiis eum harum, veritatis cumque commodi doloremque. Repellat, nulla dolores. Sint beatae culpa sit itaque quod delectus quam ratione optio quaerat minus explicabo aspernatur facilis rem eos dolorem illum voluptatum, repellat blanditiis sequi fugit magni! Fugit, nihil. Ab asperiores eveniet sit excepturi delectus id! Repellendus nostrum nihil libero rem eligendi architecto, debitis excepturi quia expedita earum, quod provident et cumque soluta repellat tenetur sint sit id quo similique quos. Soluta voluptas rem similique reiciendis, dignissimos minima beatae, illum harum delectus dolor ex omnis non. Autem architecto dolorem fugit repellendus tempore et facere quia vel reiciendis, corrupti, molestias in eaque voluptas amet nihil culpa, minus distinctio maxime libero unde hic exercitationem cumque? Maiores quam magnam accusamus dignissimos illo voluptates adipisci voluptatum quia, voluptatem quis asperiores, est a. Officia sequi ad sit sapiente ea perferendis praesentium nemo corrupti eligendi? Quaerat id dolor cupiditate culpa alias eum pariatur illo, dolore sint explicabo at assumenda ex voluptatibus dicta fuga asperiores animi quasi nam suscipit saepe facere ab ducimus qui labore? Vitae consectetur laudantium dignissimos magni ex quis, veniam sint dolor totam assumenda numquam cupiditate, quas quos? Et error dicta exercitationem ab impedit obcaecati asperiores, vitae fuga corrupti ad enim, a eius magnam est unde voluptatibus quasi quas eos aut maxime, necessitatibus deserunt animi illo. Impedit ducimus recusandae quaerat inventore culpa provident sunt voluptate vero autem! Magni blanditiis, distinctio labore accusantium veritatis repellendus quos velit praesentium sed optio reprehenderit tenetur exercitationem laboriosam enim. Assumenda, quibusdam non nam aliquam quod hic veritatis, natus corporis nisi ea, laudantium atque velit laboriosam animi similique. Delectus sunt similique quibusdam facilis, in eveniet aliquam sapiente. Quas eveniet soluta minima animi eos, qui beatae placeat repellat nihil, doloribus, minus rem voluptates iste veritatis voluptatem culpa facere perferendis suscipit ad ducimus! Quas, doloremque reiciendis modi ducimus doloribus perspiciatis sequi voluptas voluptatibus molestiae reprehenderit sunt ipsum minima veniam accusamus necessitatibus, distinctio itaque dolorum obcaecati placeat excepturi quidem! Rerum obcaecati delectus temporibus quaerat ab laudantium. Dolorum, deserunt debitis maxime aut, consequatur amet soluta eaque accusantium harum nemo dolorem velit laborum illo similique reiciendis impedit omnis officia earum quam. Obcaecati eveniet iste quidem voluptates consequuntur. Eius delectus est cum iusto velit architecto quia omnis amet aliquam aspernatur, voluptates, officiis tempora impedit, deleniti iure accusamus suscipit natus asperiores dignissimos reprehenderit! Repellendus quae possimus sed. Ab, incidunt, nobis voluptates at a nemo mollitia eum rem quo rerum sapiente non fugit? Animi nihil incidunt error soluta laboriosam, harum, expedita atque inventore ipsum modi placeat? Vitae molestias cupiditate odio dicta perferendis mollitia tenetur ipsa, eos quibusdam dolores atque et pariatur saepe iste laboriosam error impedit debitis ab temporibus harum optio. Aut eveniet eaque iure facere libero, corrupti odio harum, provident culpa, repudiandae totam nesciunt in delectus neque nobis soluta dolor temporibus laudantium minima nemo vitae cum sapiente? Mollitia quasi aliquid unde dignissimos dolorem similique repudiandae. Cum, labore dignissimos. Distinctio, voluptate aperiam ut libero vel fugiat, temporibus, facere iusto possimus sit soluta doloribus placeat ullam obcaecati ex ipsam repellat. Quas dolorem, laborum, officiis nesciunt vero dicta ullam, voluptates harum esse excepturi iusto. Ex neque eum magnam illo, blanditiis, quasi suscipit doloribus, repellendus fugiat deleniti minus quisquam corporis odit corrupti doloremque non aliquam sit. Dolorum porro, odio unde ut mollitia consequatur ipsa. Labore in amet tenetur deleniti dicta fugit odio. Assumenda officia accusantium provident necessitatibus tempora voluptatem. Nesciunt dolorum officia fuga accusamus atque alias, rerum aut fugiat, necessitatibus voluptatem repellendus laborum doloremque, aliquid sed suscipit explicabo obcaecati. Suscipit, consequuntur praesentium aliquid laborum voluptas iusto a necessitatibus assumenda ea hic eos accusamus maiores, harum dolorum dolor at, nisi aperiam placeat aliquam quis sapiente accusantium. Assumenda ad accusantium maiores voluptatibus, quis quidem, eos sit rem saepe sapiente ex optio officia quas explicabo vel natus quos mollitia officiis dignissimos voluptas, incidunt nihil? Amet veniam incidunt deleniti, est veritatis aliquid iusto quidem. Fuga, sequi soluta. Eaque recusandae et dolores ab consequatur placeat esse ducimus eos soluta aperiam aspernatur, distinctio nisi magnam id, assumenda, corrupti amet asperiores. Qui, in. Omnis reprehenderit similique ex aliquam nesciunt sequi officia totam natus et dignissimos in iusto laborum velit, labore deserunt minus vitae facilis, odio recusandae maiores molestias ipsa ducimus at. Error explicabo nam excepturi expedita, inventore officiis ad sed debitis voluptatibus autem odit fuga animi earum aspernatur libero mollitia soluta atque suscipit tempora? Voluptatem, eveniet accusamus. Quidem nam deleniti, debitis ipsam tenetur quisquam. Pariatur repudiandae minima ipsa quisquam tempore ullam inventore maxime veritatis accusantium cum, labore eveniet doloribus similique odit voluptatem architecto a in! Quam, ducimus minus nostrum sint voluptate, quasi labore officiis corporis enim molestias placeat eligendi fugit beatae nobis sed debitis dolorum, suscipit vero ipsam autem non earum iste? A odit doloribus sunt consequatur eius deleniti aperiam accusantium nostrum illo voluptas sed dolore ipsa alias, eum nam quasi, voluptatem quibusdam rerum. Velit, rem architecto ipsa illum adipisci animi recusandae! Quasi ut enim, placeat, vel iste debitis ipsam minus doloremque quam eveniet error amet repellat vero at, libero laboriosam eos accusamus accusantium officia earum laudantium aperiam aliquid. Perferendis obcaecati necessitatibus consectetur possimus. Ab inventore culpa explicabo distinctio maiores obcaecati dolores facere, nulla tempora incidunt!</p>
</div>
```

**результат работы html,body{background-image}**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не знаю почему так, та и оперы нет у меня. Попробуй сделать фон по локальной ссылке, а не с другого домена. например "../img/bg.png"

Comment: я делал так ... ни чего не меняется

Comment: Я не знаю ни одного браузера в котором `background-image:` не  работал бы....

Comment: @Air только смотрите в opera : https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/VXzOPO

Comment: @Air что бы заработало перед body поставьте html...это одно из причин почему существует html,body{ style}

Comment: Я только оперой и пользуюсь... А ничего, что ты пока  задаешь картинку а потом ее перекрываешь цветом.....

Comment: @Air убери вообще background-color фон вообще белый станет

Comment: @Air а вот если через запятую поставить html,body то всё будет тип топ но фон будет дублироваться

Comment: посмотри мой ответ и поймешь

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75048/discussion-between---and-air).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может тебе есть смысл создать некий div обертку который будет на весь экран во всем проекте, и уже от него плясать? тег body не очень хорош для картинок, максимум для background-color использовать + из личного опыта, если на него привязывать картинки с паралаксом он может очень сильно просаживать браузер при скролле

Comment: это вариант но не решение ... я же спросил о кроссбраузерной высоте background - если высота страницы 10000px должна быть одинаковой с высотой страницы в 1000px и что бы не быть слижком уж умным я даже пример показал ... где фон меньше страницы

Comment: хотя я понимаю что фоны или вообще не использовать или использовать бесшовные фоны или background-color или на крайний случай background-attachment :fixed

Answer (score 2):

Изначально  `body и html` не имеют высоты...

```js
console.log(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('body'))['height']);
console.log(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('html'))['height']);
```

Что бы все работало Этим двум элементом надо задать высоту...
Я пользуюсь всегда такой конструкцией, и у меня нет проблем таких...

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all .3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://fullhdpictures.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Eiffel-Tower-Wallpaper-HD.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: ну вот мы пришли к тому о чём я задал вопрос - эта констсрукция дублирует фон этот же фон на мобильниках .. при том паралаксе что я дал в примере ... это очень хорошо видно с мобильников и всё равно если контент большой фона не хватает ... и потому я собственно и задал этот вопрос ... наверно ответа на него не существует ... background-attachment:fixed ; не то поведение которое я хотел добиться  но только оно даёт такую возможность хотя скролл нужен вместе с фоном